# What is the function of this circuit? (Included an op-amp, capacitors and resistors)

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, filter

What is the function of this circuit? 
What is the role of the C2 in Op-amp's input?
This is probably a filter circuit but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: It's function is to confuse you. For starters, a 741 can't operate from a 5V supply.

Comment: @brhans Maybe they mean one of the 741 variants like the 6741 - see https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TLV6741DCKR/296-48176-1-ND/8347491 - perfectly fine on 5V

Comment: OK, this is a mistake in the schematic circuit and Suppose that the supply is +15V to OP-AMP.

Comment: The circuit cannot operate in a linear mode because there is no negative DC feedback (no stable operating point). In contrary, we have positive DC feedback. It provides a kind of switching operation.

Comment: This is a great way to ensure all the power supply trash gets to upset the zero-crossings of a Schmidtt Trigger squaring circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The large amount of positive feedback gives a strong hint, but if you change the opamp to something slightly more sensible than a 741 and run it through a simulator then you can observe its behavior:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7Rv9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]
Its function appears to be to filter and shape a low-ish frequency input signal into an output square wave.
There's some simple low-pass filtering going on with R2, C1, C3 and C2 more-or-less 'shorts' the opamp's inputs at 'high' frequencies.
The feedback resistor R4, along with voltage divider R1 + R3 create a 'Schmitt Trigger' behavior due to R4's positive feedback - ensuring that the output will be driven either 'high' or 'low' with no stable state in between.